# Prove given group has subgroup with order $k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group with order $2^{t}k$ where $t,k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k$ odd. Suppose $G$ contains an element $x$ with order $2^t$. Prove that the elements of $G$ having odd order form a subgroup with order $k$.

I have tried many approaches, yet I have not been able to prove it. I first started with looking at $\langle x \rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First show that <$x$> is normal in $G$; then consider the factor group and properties of the associated homomorphism.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. Yet, I have to confess I am not so familiar with factor groups, as I am a first year student. Is there any different approach to it?